# Popup.js - call a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I know this is really basic, but I can't find an answer. How can I call a popup within a condition? For example:

```
if(error.length != 0){
    console.log(error);     
    popup({
        content : '<p>Not allowed</p>',
        type    : 'html'
    });         
}
```

My page contains an import

```
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.popup.min.js' />"></script>
```

I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: popup is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(error.length != 0){
    console.log(error); 
    var popup = ({
        content : '<p>Not allowed</p>',
        type    : 'html'
    }); 
}
```

Comment: there is no error in console but a popup does not appear

Comment: then check script url . I mean are you calling it correct?

Comment: code is not showing error maybe it's because of browser. try this: able and disable "block popup windows" in your browser. also try the code in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any direct loading in `jquery.popup.min.js` you can use `color box`. see the example.[More demos here.](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

```js
if(1){ // your condition here

$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

**USING CLICK ON LINK IN popup.js**

```js
function check(val){
        //console.log(error);    
        if(val != 0){ 
      $('.html_popup').popup({
      content : '<h1>This is some HTML for non zero</h1>',
      type : 'html'
    });  
        }else{

         $('.html_popup').popup({
               content : '<h1>This is some HTML for 0</h1>',
               type : 'html'
             });  

        }

}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://docs.toddish.co.uk/js/plugins/jquery.popup.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://docs.toddish.co.uk/css/plugins/popup.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="html_popup" style="width:100px;" onclick='check(1)'> click me</a>
```